# How do I do redirect while keeping url in codeigniter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, url, routes

I'm using Codeigniter 3.0 and have two DNS mapped to the web server, "a.com" and "b.com" respectively.
I am redirected to "b.com/i/" when I type a.com in my browser, but I want to keep "a.com" in my browser window 
For example, if you type "a.com/abc", "a.com/test" , each redirects to "b.com/i/abc", "b.com/i/test" , but the browser window displays "a.com/abc", "a.com/test" .
I has a controller called I.php, but abc and test are not method names, but are branched through segments.

There are several "abc" and "test", and they can be added continuously in the future, so they cannot be modified continuously in the configuration file or code.

```
$route['i/(:any)'] = 'i/index/';
$route['i/(:any)/board/(:any)'] = 'i/index';
```

The first any is a segment like abc or test

.htaccess is shown below.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://b.com/i/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

This setting redirects, but a.com is not maintained in the browser window

A conclusion is

1. If I access "a.com/abc ", it works as "b.com/i/abc " in the backend, but it appears as "a.com/abc " in the browser
2. If I access "b.com/i/test ", the url will work as it is

What should I do?

Comment: That's not a redirect, that's a proxy.

Comment: @Sammitch     ProxyPreserveHost On

    ProxyPass /abc http://b.com/i/abc
    ProxyPassReverse /abc http://b.com/i/abc  I solved it like this. Thank you.